# Update data through text boxes to excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

with the below code I am trying to update data from UserForm to excel sheet name "ItemList", I have one text Box available with Unique Item ID which I am getting from excel sheet, through this text box I am trying to update data in the excel sheet. but this code is not working on my current form.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click() 'UPDATE CHANGES
  
Dim n As Integer
Dim q As Variant
Dim o As Worksheet
Set o = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ItemList")

 On Error Resume Next
 q = Application.Match(Me.TextBox3.Value, o.Range("A2:A"), 0)

For n = 0 To 6
o.Range("E" & q).Value = CLng(Me.TextBoxSMALL.Value)
q = q + 1
o.Range("E" & q).Value = CLng(Me.TextBoxmedium.Value)
q = q + 1
o.Range("E" & q).Value = CLng(Me.TextBoxlarge.Value)
q = q + 1
o.Range("E" & q).Value = CLng(Me.TextBoxXLarge.Value)
q = q + 1
o.Range("E" & q).Value = CLng(Me.TextBoxXXLarge.Value)
q = q + 1
o.Range("E" & q).Value = CLng(Me.TextBoxXXXLLARGE.Value)
q = q + 1
Next n
End Sub
```

Please have look at my code and let me know where I am doing mistakes.in the result of this code, I am getting values full in the whole column "E", this MATCH Fuction is not working properly or maybe I am not using it in right way.

Comment: If you remove the `On Error Resume Next` it should tell you the errors so that you can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: But `o.Range("A2:A")` is not a valid range. Either use  `o.Range("A:A")` or some kind of last row implementation.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Thanks for your reply, Yes I try o.range("A: A")  but I got the same result. is there any other way to get the exact match

Comment: If you step throught the code (F8), what is your value for q? Are you sure there is a value in the range matching textbox 3?  You could use [find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find), something like    `q = o.Range("A:A").Find(Me.TextBox3.Value).Row`

Comment: The main issue is that the value of textbox3 is not increasing to get the 2nd Item number it's stuck on first only.

Comment: The main issue is that the value of textbox3 is not increasing to get the 2nd Item number it's stuck on first only.

Comment: Well you aren't changing the value of textbox3, only the variable that is assigned the same value. You'd have to send it back with `Me.TextBox3.Value = q` Or `Me.TextBox3.Value = Me.TextBox3.Value + 1` or however you want to increment that.

Answer (score 0):

you should not put q as Variant, Dim q As Integer

Comment: thanks for your reply, I've tried both types Variant and integer. but nothing change.